# @Autowired not working in Spring restful web service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, jersey

I am developing application using Struts2 + Spring4 + Hibernate4 with RESTful web service. I have configured Hibernate in Spring bean file. For RESTful web service I have excluded URL in `struts.xml` using

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/service/.*"/>
```

If I access `sessionFactory` object in any action class it works fine. But if I access it in my web service it gives `NullPointerException`.

After searching on Google I found that if we bypass URL from Struts it does not allow to initialize object using `@Autowired` annotation.

How to sort out this thing? I have searched on Google but nothing useful found.

**This is my service:**

```
@Path("service/account-management")
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @POST
    @PermitAll
    @Path("/accounts")
    public Response getAllAccounts() {
        System.out.println(sessionFactory);
         Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         List<VbarAccount> personList = session.createQuery("from TEST").list();
         System.out.println(personList);
         session.close();
         return Response.status(200).build();
    }

}
```

**This is my bean mapping:**

```
<bean id="accountService" class="com.xxx.yyy.services.impl.AccountServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Not a S2 issue. Spring should know about your service to inject something there.

Comment: @Aleksandr M I have mapped that service in bean file. but same thing happening. Even i not able to load properties files in excluded urls

Comment: @AleksandrM ok i have added code snippet. 'System.out.println(sessionFactory);' is printing null but same thing works in action class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowired works if you get the object from Spring, and the object should be configured as a Spring bean before you get it from the context. To configure some class as a Spring bean sometimes only needed to put some `@Component` annotation and ensure that the class is scanned for annotations. In you case a `@Service` annotation is more appropriate

```
@Service
@Path("service/account-management")
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
```

In the `applicationContext.xml` you should have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy.services"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting here that Spring 3.1 introduces LocalSessionFactoryBuilder, which is expressly designed for use within @Bean methods.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.html

In your XML you also can use the hibernate config also :

```
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
  </props>
     </property>
        <property name="yourGivenName">
    </property>
  </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
```

or can use the java based bean config :
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
sessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}

and then you can use it inside your Spring bean:

```java
    @Autowired
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

and then inside of your method:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```